# 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'zipcodes'

Tags: sql, database, mysql-error-1064, yii-extensions

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
test.zipcodes.ZIP,
test.zipcodes.State,
test.dealers.dealer_name,
test.dealers.address1,
test.dealers.address2,
test.dealers.city,
test.dealers.state,
locator.locations.storename,
locator.locations.address,
locator.locations.city,
locator.locations.state
FROM
test.dealers ,
locator.locations ,
test.zipcodes
INNER JOIN 
test.zipcodes ON test.zipcodes.State = test.dealers.state AND test.zipcodes.State =  
locator.locations.state 
WHERE test.zipcodes.ZIP = 123456
```

[Err] 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'zipcodes'

databases:

```
1- test->(database)->zipcodes(table)
2- test->(database)->dealers(table)
3- locator->(database)->locations(table)
```

I want to fetch results in a way that when I search ZIP from `test.zipcodes` it fetches the states of that zip from that table and then check this specific state in `test.dealers` and `locator.locations` table to returns me collective results from both tables for that state.

Comment: please anybody help in getting through from this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: Yuo are joining the zipcodes table twice

Comment: can you please write the rectified query for me? please write one. i am unable to understand.

Comment: This old question appears to have answers that the OP was not satisfied with, and since then there have been no clarifications to the question. I'm therefore proposing it is closed as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax to join tables

```
SELECT distinct 
       test.zipcodes.ZIP,
       test.zipcodes.State,
       test.dealers.dealer_name,
       test.dealers.address1,
       test.dealers.address2,
       test.dealers.city,
       test.dealers.state,
       locator.locations.storename,
       locator.locations.address,
       locator.locations.city,
       locator.locations.state
FROM test.dealers
INNER JOIN test.zipcodes ON test.zipcodes.State = test.dealers.state
inner join locator.locations on test.zipcodes.State = locator.locations.state 
WHERE test.zipcodes.ZIP = 123456
```

Comment: this is perfect query to some extent but it duplicates the records. like each record is repeated 10times.

Comment: @user3040719 - how many identical "states" are there in the various tables?

Comment: i dont know why it duplicates each record 10 times. can you please rectify this?

Comment: You should read a book about SQL. This is basic knowledge. If you join tables then you get the combined data. You have to group by specific data or finer how you join the tables to get more precise data.

Comment: I want to fetch results that when i search ZIP from test.zipcodes it fetches the states of that ZIP from test.zipcodes and then check the state of this zip in test.dealers and locator.locations table respectively to returns me collective results from both tables for that state.

Comment: thanks for both of your answers. the issue is still not solved

Comment: To solve this you need to show a simplifed example of your data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're selecting from `test.zipcodes` **twice**, without providing an alias for either table. While the quick fix is to add table aliases, the underlying problem is probably an error in your query.

Do you really want to select from `test.zipcodes` twice?

---

The problem you're now facing is that there is no way to combine dealers and locations in a meaningful way.
Let's say you have 3 dealers and 5 locations for a certain state. Do you want to see:

```
DEALER   STORE
===============
dealer1  store1
dealer1  store2
dealer1  store3
dealer1  store4
dealer1  store5
dealer2  store1
dealer2  store2
dealer2  store3
dealer2  store4
dealer2  store5
dealer3  store1
dealer3  store2
dealer3  store3
dealer3  store4
dealer3  store5
```

But perhaps those are the 'duplicates' you mentioned. They aren't duplicates, since every combination of dealer and store in unique. But perhaps you're expecting:

```
DEALER   STORE
===============
dealer1  store1
dealer2  store2
dealer3  store3
         store4
         store5
```

The problem with the latter is that there is no meaningful relation between dealers and locations, they just happen to be on the same line.

If it's the former you want:

```
SELECT 
  zc.zip,
  zc.state,
  deal.dealer_name,
  deal.address1,
  deal.address2,
  deal.city,
  deal.state,
  loc.storename,
  loc.address,
  loc.city,
  loc.state
FROM test.zipcodes zc
LEFT JOIN test.dealers deal ON (zc.state = deal.state)
LEFT JOIN locator.locations loc ON (zc.state = loc.state)
WHERE zc.zip = 123456
```

Comment: I want to fetch results that when i search ZIP from test.zipcodes it fetches the states of that ZIP from test.zipcodes and then check the state of this zip in test.dealers and locator.locations table respectively to returns me collective results from both tables for that state.